# LOTs of filtered ports on my server

Tags: server, nmap, audit

I'm setting up a dedicated server (4 days uptime, not in production yet).
I'm a coder, not a sysadmin or a security expert so bear with me.

I just tried to portscan it with `nmap -p- -T5 -Pn -sV -v` to see how it looks from the outside and this was the result

```
PORT      STATE    SERVICE         VERSION
22/tcp    open     ssh             OpenSSH 7.2p2 Ubuntu 4ubuntu2.2 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
80/tcp    open     http            Apache httpd 2.4.18 ((Ubuntu))
445/tcp   filtered microsoft-ds
554/tcp   open     tcpwrapped
4223/tcp  filtered unknown
6010/tcp  open     x11?
7070/tcp  open     tcpwrapped
7190/tcp  filtered unknown
8078/tcp  filtered unknown
16946/tcp filtered unknown
17444/tcp filtered unknown
27238/tcp filtered unknown
29292/tcp filtered unknown
29683/tcp filtered unknown
32786/tcp filtered sometimes-rpc25
41551/tcp filtered unknown
43397/tcp filtered unknown
48553/tcp filtered unknown
53487/tcp filtered unknown
54580/tcp filtered unknown
55489/tcp filtered unknown
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel
```

Needless to say this scared me a bit, I checked the `history` of all users (root and myself, there are no other login users) and found nothing weird.
I have continuous bruteforces on ssh but I believe this is normal, fail2ban is doing its job well.

After a reboot, stopping apache and trying another nmap I got this.

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE    VERSION
22/tcp   open  ssh        OpenSSH 7.2p2 Ubuntu 4ubuntu2.2 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
554/tcp  open  tcpwrapped
7070/tcp open  tcpwrapped
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel
```

Why do I have so many filtered (and open) ports?

On this server I only installed the LAMP stack, kvm and snort.
Snort doesn't have the a log reader yet but it's all on the DB (Could you recommend one aswell? I require PHP7)

**UPDATE:**
The ports result filtered while snort is *not running*, if I start it only the open ports are displayed.
Also, the filtered ports change every time i run `nmap`.
Why the behaviour is so inconsistent, could it be simply packet loss on the SYN/ACK?
I don't understand this behaviour and I would like to.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136683/why-are-some-ports-reported-by-nmap-filtered-and-not-the-others

Comment: Do you know what `filtered` means? That might clear things up for you.

Comment: Sort of, as far as I know a port results `closed` when the firewall actively negates an handshake, while `filtered` means there is no response at all.
Now, I'm not worried that `filtered` is a security risk by itself, I wonder why I have so many "weird" filtered ports on he first scan and after a reboot it all looks normal.
Again, I'm no expert, just trying to learn.